# Reverse engineering database adds in Index attributes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am converting a database to Entity Framework Core with a code-first approach.

- I started with creating a separate project
- Add EF Core Database First Wizard
- Select EF Core 7 as the version
- Select everything
- Check Pluralise or Singularise
- Check Use DataAnnotation

I carried out the same process a few years ago but with EF6 which created all the Models etc and were stored in a separate class library project (Core).

I have two class library projects:

- `Core` - stores all the DB entities.
- `Infrastructure` - all CRUD type operations which also has a ref to the `Core` project and has EF installed.

The above steps generates the `DbContext` and the model classes for me. When I look at the generated model classes, I notice this index configuration has been added to each class:

```
[Table("Basket")]
[Index("CountryId", Name = "IX_CountryID")]
[Index("DeliveryCostId", Name = "IX_DeliveryCostId")]
[Index("DeliveryCountryId", Name = "IX_DeliveryCountryId")]
[Index("DeliveryTitleId", Name = "IX_DeliveryTitleID")]
[Index("PromotionalCodeId", Name = "IX_PromotionalCodeId")]
[Index("TitleId", Name = "IX_TitleId")]
[Index("UserId", Name = "IX_UserId")]
public partial class Basket....
```

I don't know what purpose the `Index` annotations have with the model but in order for this to compile in my `Models/Core` class library I need to install Entity Framework Core.

I noticed `Index` is coming from `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` in order to resolve those `Index` attribute errors whereas in my EF6 project they came from the `DataAnnotations` class (which was ok as I didn't need EF to be installed) however I feel this shouldn't be the case as my `Core` class library would be dependent on the EF Core Framework.

Had a look here but the examples don't mention this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/core/modeling/

I also tried to re-run the above steps but this time without selecting `DataAnnotation` but the issue with this is it loses all the `[Required]` attributes for the fields in the classes.

Would it be correct to delete these entries and carry on as normal? Would i lose any specific behaviour or cause issues down the line? Or is there a way to move this into the Infrastructure project which would have EF Core installed?

Comment: You can get these attributes from the small EFCore.Abstractions package that does not have any other dependencies

Comment: I installed Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions and that resolved the compiling issues. Feel free to add as an answer and i can mark it as such

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get these attributes from the small EFCore.Abstractions package that does not have any other dependencies.